# Ios pageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I try to set up a `UIPageViewController` component, but I cannot. How do I fix it?

This is a piece of my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    private var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    private let contenteImges = ["7272LOGO",
                                 "spBc",
                                 "tuto1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControl()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    private func createPageViewController()
    {
        let PageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self

        if contenteImges.count > 0
        {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
            PageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController?
    {

    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return contentImages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

It throws errors on seven lines:

1.`pageController.dataSource = self`

2.`pageViewController = pageController`

3.`let itemController = viewController as PageItemController`

4.`let itemController = viewController as PageItemController`

5.`if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {`

6.`private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController?`

7.`return contentImages.count`

In points 1, 2, 5, and 7 it shows me "Use of unresolved identifier". In points 3, 4, and 6, "Use of undeclared type".

Comment: 3/4/6 are because you need to import whatever file has `PageItemController` declared in it. The others are because of inconsistent spelling of your variable names (pageController vs PageController, contentImages vs contenteImges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case 1: PageController.dataSource = self

case 2: pageViewController = PageController

case 3: No declaration of PageItemController class

case 4: case 3

case 5: itemController is not instanciated because of case 3

case 6: Unrecognized return type because of case 3

case 7:  return contenteImges.count